# How can i change the full background of my div inside a div

Tags: html, css, background

**div inside a div**

[image]

How can I change the background of the div with the title of Lawyer's Kit with the 3 `<ul>` I want that full div to have a color white background but it seems only with the text will have a color white background.

here's my code

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://my-smashing.smashingapps.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/blurbackgrounds9.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.container input {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.inform {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inform h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.inform ul {
  font-family: Impact;
}

.iform {
  margin-top: 10%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form action='' method='POST'>
    <div class='inform'>
      <h1>Lawyer's Kit</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> Backup your files </li>
        <li> Reminder for your appointments </li>
        <li> Secure your data </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='iform'>
      <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='UserName'>
      <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'></br>
      <button class='login' value='submit' name='submit'> Log In </button>
      <h5>I forgot my password</h5>
      <button class='bregister' href='register.php'>REGISTER</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Please take more care next time. Also run a w3org validation over your code - you for example have a `</br>` which is an illegal tag. Is your problem not just adding a`background-color: white` to container?

Comment: yes i want the class of .inform have a full white back ground

Comment: It does. Also in your picture. The div is not bigger than what you see.

Comment: let me clear myself, the bottom of the text only have the white background, i want to extend my white background to the border

Comment: Which border. Please draw something on the picture you uploaded. The inform is completely white. If you want it to extend to the bottom, you need to give it a height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the question how to strech div height to its parent

The solution is adding `position:relative` to parent div ,
adding `position:absolute;height:100%` will solve your issue . The below code is working example

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://my-smashing.smashingapps.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/blurbackgrounds9.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border: solid;
  position:relative;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.container input {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.inform {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

.inform h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.inform ul {
  font-family: Impact;
}

.iform {
  margin-top: 10%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form action='' method='POST'>
    <div class='inform'>
      <h1>Lawyer's Kit</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> Backup your files </li>
        <li> Reminder for your appointments </li>
        <li> Secure your data </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='iform'>
      <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='UserName'>
      <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'></br>
      <button class='login' value='submit' name='submit'> Log In </button>
      <h5>I forgot my password</h5>
      <button class='bregister' href='register.php'>REGISTER</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you want this